# Updating React component's state with setInterval function

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am working on Timer implementation in React.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function start() {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Parent Component</div>
      <p> value of count is: {count}</p>
      
      <button onClick={start}>Start counter</button>

      
    </>
  );
}
```

when i click the start counter button, it only increments count once,
somehow i figured out i need to use useEffect. but dont know how to do that.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic timer stale state blunder. You are accessing closed-over stale state in the timer interval callback function.

This is easily resolved by using a functional state update so you aren't using the closed over initial state value.

```
export default function Parent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function start() {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count => count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>Parent Component</div>
      <p> value of count is: {count}</p>
      
      <button onClick={start}>Start counter</button>

      
    </>
  );
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit updating-react-components-state-with-setinterval-function]